# UICollectionViewListCell Text Indentation Using UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewlistcell

I have a section content insert of 20 left and 20 right for my `UIViewController` I have adjusted my separatorInsets within the `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` for this case:

```
var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        configuration.headerMode = .none
        configuration.showsSeparators = true
        configuration.itemSeparatorHandler = { (indexPath, separatorConfiguration) in
            var configuration = separatorConfiguration
            configuration.topSeparatorVisibility = .hidden
            configuration.bottomSeparatorInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)
            if indexPath == self.collectionView.lastIndexPath() {
                configuration.bottomSeparatorVisibility = .hidden
            }
            return configuration
        }
        return .list(using: configuration, layoutEnvironment: environment)
```

Everything seems to be working fine on the simulator however, on the device the text within the `UICollectionViewListCell` reverts back to the default of 16.

Is there anyway to change this? I have tried `indentationWidth = 20` within my `UICollectionViewListCell` although it doesn't seem to be working.